# Python read files and parse lines

Tags: python

In some directory (/patch/in) I have files named:

```
S0000001.ARQ
S0000001.SRQ
S0000002.ARQ
S0000002.SRQ
```

...and so on

Each file has basically same structure in it but with different values, example:
`

```
----- BEGIN REQUEST -----
RQID=S0000001.ACE
POLICY=AUT
G=STEVEN
SN=JEENS
SERIALNUMBER=060294223
DOCUMENT=S0000001
----- END REQUEST -----
```

I want to read every file from dir and take out some values to use them later.
What I have right now:

```
path = 'patch/in/*.ARQ'
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:
    f=open(file, 'r')
    print '%s' %  f.readlines()
```

I want to print out(store) lines:

```
POLICY=AUT
G=STEVEN
SN=JEENS
SERIALNUMBER=060294223
DOCUMENT=S0000001
```

and then the actual values:

```
AUT
STEVEN
EENS
060294223
S0000001
```

Comment: And what have you tried yet?

Comment: For each file, have a loop to go over the lines vs reading them all in at once. Then take a at the "split" command to split each line on the "=" and put the results in a list. Then afterward you have all the data in a list. If you aren't sure how to do this, I would recommend going through a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code reading out the files is working, you can parse the lines as follow:

```
import re

...
...

lines = f.read()
keyValues = re.findall('^(\\w+)=(.+)$', lines, re.MULTILINE)

print('Lines containing key and value:')
for key, value in keyValues:
    print('{}={}'.format(key, value))

print('Actual values:')
for key, value in keyValues:
    print(value)
```

**Edit:** Updated read file method

Comment: This seems working, thx! But only if I use read:
`lines = f.read()
    keyValues = re.findall('^(\\w+)=(.+)$', lines, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: You're right! `readlines()` returns a list of strings while `read()` returns the whole file as one string.

Answer (score 0):

You could print lines containing '=' as you go and accumulate the values to print at the end.

```
path = 'patch/in/*.ARQ'
files=glob.glob(path)   
for filename in files:
    values = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if '=' in line:
                print line,
                key, value = line.strip().split('=')
                values.append(value)
    print '\n'.join(values)
```